# elasticsearch: keep indexes in sync after clone/reindex

Tags: elasticsearch

I wonder if this feature is supported, assuming we use the clone or reindex API, so:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "users",
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "name": "foo"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "users_extended"
  }
}
```

assuming, this copy X numbers of docs into the new index... does updates made into docs in "**users** propagate down into **users_extended**?

I'm thinking about creating a type for the index, let's say **user** and then use logstash to sync the source of truth, something like:

```
output {  
    if [type] == "user" {
        elasticsearch {  
            hosts => "..." 
            index => "users"
            #...
  
        }
    } 
    if [type] == "user" {
        elasticsearch {  
            hosts => "..." 
            index => "users_extended"
            #...   
        }
    }
}
```

But you can see the pattern of extending this config file every time we keep adding more and more copies, I just wonder if there's a better way to do so.

Comment: I'm just curious what additional information the `users_extended` index would contain? Do you run a script or a pipeline during the reindex to enrich the user data?

Comment: yeah, I'm thinking in making so kind of datalakeish let's say for users, but not all my use cases for users search requires the whole information, and I dont want these features to ba taxed for it, for sample, if you are interested to find for a name and id... i would reindex into this to props only

Comment: I think you're overthinking it and trying to improve a performance that you never witnessed to be bad in the first place. Remember that premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: fair point! sadly i don't get to make this call, I need to test a few hypothesis and provide a few options